# R highcharter - adding total in tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, tooltip, r-highcharter

i want to add a total or a sum of y in tooltip

here is my example :

`ga=gapminder %>% group_by(year,continent) %>% summarise(pop=sum(pop))`

```
hchart(ga,"line",hcaes(x=year,y=pop,group=continent)) %>% 
hc_tooltip(          
    shared = TRUE,        
    sort=TRUE,

    footerFormat='{ sum(point.y)}'   ### something like that 

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done using the tooltip.formatter function available from the Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article showing how to work with Highcharts JavaScript syntax in R: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR39-dztCuBUrncLQHEo9yNin00lRZfSqKY1JqAdvMU7KkokZGfTfj5DYB4